# listing out strings with the Regexp_Like() function

Tags: sql, regex

I am curious to see if there is a way to input a list of strings within the regexp_like() function in SQL.

Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_1
AND REGEXP_LIKE(COLUMN_1, '2007239,;
2007294,
2007296,
2007295,
2007297,
1398852,
1398837,
1398744')
;
```

I understand that this is not possible but is there a way to do this without being too repetitive (i.e. having too many regexp_like() in one query).

Comment: Maybe you could share some input samples so that people could have a look what are you actually after?

Answer (score 1):

You could use PL/SQL to create a explicit cursor(loop) to run query with each like string.

see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_cursors.htm  for cursor example

Answer (score 0):

Just use `|` in your regex.

```
REGEXP_LIKE(COLUMN_1, '\b(2007239|2007294|2007296)\b')
```